# Django - Constructing a Model Object With a User

Tags: python, django, constructor, model

I have the following model:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from cms.models import Item
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Cart(models.Model):  
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    items = models.ManyToManyField('cms.Item')
```

I tried constructing an object of this type two different ways. Method 1:

```
cart = Cart(owner=request.user)
cart.save()
```

Method 2:

```
cart = Cart()
cart.owner = request.user
cart.save()
```

The first way works and the second generates a NOT NULL constraint failed error. Why does this happen?

Comment: As long as `request.user` is a logged-in user, then both methods should work. I can't see why they would give different results.

Comment: The two methods you are using are identical. Can you provide a full traceback or at least the actual error? You might want to check if your request.user is populated.

Comment: Well, I tried it again and Method 2 worked fine. I'll probably never know why it didn't the other times; I had/have a check in place and that code couldn't be reached if a user wasn't authenticated. When it wasn't working, request.user was populated.

Answer (score 0):

That is because Django model constructor check fields that he has and see the owner field is not null field and not blank.  He wants that the field not be blank because it is wrong for he. But constructor dont have value in call, and he put null on this field, but it is wrong to. And he raise error.
Sorry my language is not good.

Comment: He sets the owner field to request.user. Also, the constructor doesn't really check anything in Django models, the constraints are checked by the RDBMS when saving.

Comment: You partly don't right. Model constructor in Django check the **kwargs in himself, and set values. And check value of null parameter in field if object is related. we can see it in django Model class code.